# Customization of private message module in Drupal 7

Tags: php, html, drupal

I am working on Job portal site in drupal7,i have made one application form to apply for a job which is working fine and have used private message module.Now i need to use both whenever user apply for a job,on submit user will get a message in the inbox.Please share your knowledge.

Thank You

Comment: retrieve his mail id from the form,store it in a db and then send an email using mail server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Bhuvan Rikka said in the comments you can store the email in a db and then use it to send the email with whatever information you want to send with this:

```
<?php
$to = "$email";
$subject = "Thank you for applying for the job(or whatever you want to say)";
$txt = $message;
$headers = 'From: youremail@domain.com ' . "\r\n" .
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

You must obviously get the email from the database and store it in the $email variable before using this.

Hope this helped.